# Clickable icon displays during hover over of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have to make a `small red clickable X` that displays in the top right corner when I hover over an image.

**The theory is they can click on the X and it will handle some work and then delete the image hovered over.**

I'm extremely new to CSS so I don't have actual code.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Heres my theory:

- We add a hover background and then we set a background Url of the red image and then somehow place it in the right corner.

This isn't right and i do need to look at code as i have no real skills in this.

Comment: This is not a free coding service. You must have at least basic knowledge of the code you want to work with. Try coding your project yourself. We're here to help you if you get stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Michael_B how bout now? this is as far as ive gotten

Comment: have you worked with bootstrap modals?? for doing same stuff it might look more better...if you want i can link it in your answers

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a snippet made by me. Ask if something is not clear enough.

```css
.img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.x {
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.img:hover>.x {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="x">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm out right now I'll be home in a few hours I have some questions